# Adobe AIR HTML IDE that supports debugging?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, air

I've been trying to find an IDE that supports Adobe AIR HTML/JS app development *with debugging*.  Obviously, I can use any any HTML/JS development tool, like JetBrains WebStorm, Adobe Dreamweaver, Notepad++, or plain old Notepad, and then compile my app with the Adobe AIR SDK.

But I'm hoping there is a tool out there that supports true debugging, where you step through the code line by line (or until you hit a breakpoint), inspect variables, etc.

I've been searching and haven't been able to find anything.  Apparently Aptana allowed you to do this 3 years ago, but they dropped Adobe AIR support in 2010 and haven't added it back (and at this point, I doubt they will).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no IDE with support for this, and [FDB debugging is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504787/debugging-adobe-air-javascript-app-with-fdb-not-working/19798475#19798475). Adobe bug report on FDB issue is [here](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3658754).

Sadly, I'm getting the idea that HTML/JS apps are second-class citizens in the Adobe AIR world.  Adobe offers an excellent IDE and an expansive feature set for Flash AIR app development, but HTML/JS apps get... well, not much.

I wish it weren't so.

Answer (score 0):

[IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/flex_ide.html) support of Adobe Air includes full-featured debugging. In addition IDEA has the full functionality of WebStorm in terms of HTML/JS support.

Comment: I would love to be wrong about this, but doesn't IntelliJ IDEA only have support for ActionScript AIR projects?  It may support HTML/JS development for the web, but I don't see anywhere that indicates it supports it for AIR development.  Is there a way to make HTML/JS work with AIR, and even allow debugging?

Comment: I installed the IntelliJ IDEA trial just to confirm this, and indeed, the only place that Adobe AIR is mentioned is in the context of developing a "Flash Module" which is "intended for developing Adobe Flash platform-targeted content. Build configurations will let you create Flex or pure ActionScript applications and libraries for web (Flash Player), desktop (Adobe AIR) and the AIR mobile platform."  There is no way to create an HTML/JS AIR app, as far as I could tell.