# Debugging Adobe AIR JavaScript app with fdb not working

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, air, fdb

I've been trying to figure out a way to interactively debug an Adobe AIR JavaScript application.  There does not appear to be an IDE that supports this (is there?).

However, there is fdb, which [according to this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fd7.html), you can use to debug Adobe AIR apps.  It says the following:

*If an AIR application is SWF-based, the debugger only controls the execution of ActionScript code. If the AIR application is HTML-based, then the debugger only controls the execution of JavaScript code.*

That sounds pretty unequivocally like JavaScript debugging is supported via fdb.

So, I followed the instructions. I'm on Windows 7, and I just downloaded the AIR SDK today (AIR 3.9.0).
More information on fdb commands are available [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ffb.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62063-7fed).

So I followed the instructions on debugging an AIR app with fdb.  First, I launched fdb in a terminal window.  It starts up fine.  I enter "run" and it says "Waiting for Player to connect".

I then launch my app via adl in another terminal window ("adl simple-html-app.xml"), and it starts up.  It launches a window with my AIR app, but the content is not loaded.  I see this in the fdb terminal window:

*Player connected; session starting.

Set breakpoints and then type 'continue' to resume the session.
[SWF] HelloWorld.html - 0 bytes after decompression*

0 bytes after decompression?  That immediately makes me think something is wrong.  And it's not a SWF, it's an HTML file.

Additionally, no matter what command I type, I get the same response.  "Do you want to attempt to halt execution? (y or n)."  And no matter how I response, the app remains "hung", seemingly without having executed any code?

Here's a sample session.  My commands in bold, fdb responses in italics.

**info sources**
*Do you want to attempt to halt execution? (y or n) **y**

Attempting to halt.

To help out, try nudging the Player (e.g. press a button)*
**{hit enter}**
*Do you want to attempt to halt execution? (y or n)

Not confirmed.*
**continue**
*Do you want to attempt to halt execution? (y or n)* **{hit enter}**
*Not confirmed.*
**{hit enter}**
*Do you want to attempt to halt execution? (y or n)* **{hit enter}**
*Not confirmed.*
**continue**
*Do you want to attempt to halt execution? (y or n)* **{hit enter}**
*Not confirmed.*
**continue**
*Do you want to attempt to halt execution? (y or n)* **n**
*Not confirmed.

**continue**

Do you want to attempt to halt execution? (y or n)* **y**
*Attempting to halt.

To help out, try nudging the Player (e.g. press a button)*

Am I missing a step?  How do I get command line debugging working?

-Josh

Comment: While this doesn't cover interactive debugging by stopping execution, I've had luck using Weinre while working on Html Air apps. http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

Comment: Appreciate the tip.  Hopefully I will be able to get fdb working, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is, **this is a bug**.  I **[reported it here](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3658754)**.  If this is a something you want fixed, please vote and comment on the bug report.

I would love to be wrong about this.  If anyone can provide an answer demonstrating how to get this working, I would happily accept that answer.